# Regex with dollar sign is not terminating

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

so i want to replace every `whitespace on the begging of each lane` with `#` and every `whitespace on the end of line` with `@`, but my program is not terminating it writes only `@` when as input i gave `aTAB`, like sign `a` with whitespace.

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int yylex();
%}

%%
^[[:space:]]* printf("#");
([:space:]*)$ printf("@");
%%

int main() {

  yylex();
}
```

I'm just starting to learn flex and i feel kinda confused, how does `$` sign works, shouldn't it check patter at the end of line? Thanks for help

Comment: you have only whitespaces in your line  ?

Comment: yes, there is only `a` sign and whitespace

Comment: actually i make it work with `+` instead of `*` but sill i have no idea how this works

Comment: you mean ([:space:]+)$ printf("@"); works ?

Comment: yes, it works this way

Comment: what about [[:space:]]*$ ? this should be the correct syntax, but I'm not familiar with flex ...

Comment: it didn't work but thanks for trying :)

Comment: well ... sorry, good luck then  ;)

Comment: Doesn't flex produce a warning with that file?

Comment: no it doesn't actually